# Why will script work with /bin/bash but not /bin/sh?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to understand why the script will work with `#!/bin/bash` but not `#!/bin/sh`. I am running Cygwin and both `sh.exe` and `bash.exe` seem to be identical (same file size).

```
$ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
  echo ${line:0:9}
done < <(help | head -5)

$ ./1.sh
./1.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./1.sh: line 4: `done < <(help | head -5)'

$ cat 2.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  echo ${line:0:9}
done < <(help | head -5)

$ ./2.sh
GNU bash,
These she
Type `hel
Use `info
Use `man
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite being same file, shell analyzes its own name when run and switches to either plain shell or bash mode.

Comment: [documentation](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbAH) (about the 8th paragraph in the section)

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode too

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problems

1. Bash is a superset of the Bourne shell, so many things are possible in Bash that aren't possible in more limited shells.
2. Even when *sh* is a hardlink to *bash*, it behaves differently when invokes as *sh*. Many features supported by the Bash shell will not work in this mode.

#### The Solutions

1. Remove your [bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) from the script, including nifty features like the process substitution you have on line 4.
2. Run your script as Bash, not vanilla Bourne.