# How to port this bash script to sh?

Tags: linux, shell

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read system_name mount_name
do
   echo "${system_name} ${mount_name}"
done < <(echo "select system_name, mount_name from SystemTable" | mysql ifm -uroot -pinsite3)
```

**But this does not if i change the shebang variable to #!/bin/sh** 
How to make the above script work in sh shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why will script work with /bin/bash but not /bin/sh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061727/why-will-script-work-with-bin-bash-but-not-bin-sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "select system_name, mount_name from SystemTable" | mysql ifm -uroot -pinsite3 |
while read system_name mount_name
do
   echo "${system_name} ${mount_name}"
done
```

Comment: Any idea, where can i get the specification, to understand more on this problem.

Comment: As suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061727/why-will-script-work-with-bin-bash-but-not-bin-sh), [Bash POSIX Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) explains the differences. In this case, you hit point 26 ("Process substitution is not available.").