# Change IPython/Jupyter notebook working directory

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I open a Jupyter notebook (formerly IPython) it defaults to `C:\Users\USERNAME`.

How can I change this so to another location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18901185/776637 - This should be useful.

Comment: You can change directory and then do `jupyter lab .`       
refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66395692/9283726

Answer (score 238, accepted):

`jupyter notebook --help-all` could be of help:

```
--notebook-dir=<Unicode> (NotebookManager.notebook_dir)
    Default: u'/Users/me/ipynbs'
    The directory to use for notebooks.
```

For example:

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/Users/yourname/folder1/folder2/
```

You can of course set it in your profiles if needed, you might need to escape backslash in Windows.

Note that this will override whatever path you might have set in a jupyter_notebook_config.py file.  (Where you can set a variable `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` that will be your default startup location.)

Comment: what is it for windows ?

Comment: Confirmed this does work on Mac OSX, for jupyterlab 0.31.5 / IPython 6.2.1

Comment: For Windows it is: `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=C:\my_python_project\`

Comment: That worked for me on windows 10 pro. Just open CMD and type: jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="D:\change_this_path"

Comment: this does not change the working directory in notebooks. it just sets the initial place where to look for notebooks. once you navigate/open a notebook the working directory will be wherever you opened it.

Comment: anyone has any idea for people who don't have admin rights how this can be configured. when I ran this from anaconda it automatically opens jupyter notebook and does not let me define anything

Comment: Isn't there a way to configure this via Anaconda's GUI?

Answer (score 177):

```
%pwd  #look at the current work dir
%cd   #change to the dir you want
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice tip. I was using `!cd` in python3 jupyter notebook and it doesn't work but this worked

Comment: very good answer, doesnt depend on system and actually does what is asked in question

Comment: This will not help you if you need to do relative imports.

Comment: gotta use this(%) instead of !, it wont change the working directory.

Comment: where are you entering these commands?

Comment: what is the difference between command prefixed with ! and % in jupyter notebook?

Comment: @4t8dds Any command starting with a "!" is passed to the shell like bash. You can run any bash command and linux command that are provided by the OS that is running the Jupyter notebook. However, you cannot use ! to navigate the file systems. Instead, you need to use % to change the directory.

Comment: @4t8dds A regular shell command is executed in the terminal, while a Jupyter magic command is executed in the Jupyter kernel. This means that "!cd directory" will change the working dir for the entire terminal session, while "%cd" directory will only change the working directory for the current Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 74):

**For Windows 10**

1. Look for the *jupyter_notebook_config.py* in 
   C:\Users\your_user_name\.jupyter or look it up with cortana.
2. If you don't have it, then go to the cmd line and type:

   `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
3. Open the *jupyter_notebook_config.py* and do a `ctrl-f` search for:

   `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir`
4. Uncomment it by removing the #.
5. Change it to:

   `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'C:/your/new/path'`

   Note: You can put a `u` in front of the first `'`, change `\\\\` to `/`,  or change the `'`  to `"`. I don't think it matters.
6. Go to your Jupyter Notebook link and right click  it. Select properties. Go to the Shortcut menu and click Target. Look for %USERPROFILE%. Delete it. Save. Restart Jupyter.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 had tried all previous answers and this is the only solution that worked for me!  Last step is critical. In fact, it might be the case that you don't need all previous steps if in the last step one removes %USERPROFILE% and *replaces* it by the desired directory

Answer (score 53):

As MrFancypants mentioned in the comments, if you are using [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) (which you should, since it currently supersedes the older IPython Notebook project), things are a [little different](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html). For one, there are no profiles any more.

After [installing Jupyter](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html), first check your *~/.jupyter* folder to see its content. If no config files were migrated from the default IPython profile (as they weren't in my case), create a new one for Jupyter Notebook:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

This generates *~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py* file with some helpfully commented possible options. To set the default directory add:

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'/absolute/path/to/notebook/directory'
```

As I switch between Linux and OS X, I wanted to use a path relative to my home folder (as they differ – */Users/username* and */home/username*), so I set something like:

```
import os
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox/dev/notebook')
```

Now, whenever I run `jupyter notebook`, it opens my desired notebook folder. I also version the whole *~/.jupyter* folder in my [dotfiles repository](https://github.com/metakermit/dotfiles/tree/master/jupyter.symlink) that I deploy to every new work machine.

---

As an aside, you can still use the `--notebook-dir` command line option, so maybe a simple alias would suit your needs better.

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/absolute/path/to/notebook/directory
```

Comment: I don't understand the 'u' in `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'/absolute/path/to/notebook/directory'` it seems to work fine without it

Comment: yes, it's probably not needed. It was a way to make a Unicode string in Python 2 (try `type(u'bla')` vs `type('bla')`. In Python 3 it's the same thing as the string expression without `u` (as all strings are Unicode).

Comment: cmd window in the anaconda folder, then "jupyter notebook --generate-config
", then follow the steps above. worked for me. :)

Comment: But how do I do this for an already opened notebook? That is, how to change the notebook directory after launch? Thank you

Comment: from jupyter_notebook_config.py file  ## DEPRECATED use base_url
#c.NotebookApp.base_project_url = '/'

## The base URL for the notebook server. 

c.NotebookApp.base_url = '/'

Answer (score 49):

**A neat trick for those using IPython in windows** is that you can make an ipython icon in each of your project directories designed to open with the notebook pointing at that chosen project. This helps keep things separate.

For example if you have a new project in C:\fake\example\directory

Copy an ipython notebook icon to the directory or create a new link to the windows "cmd" shell. Then right click on the icon and "Edit Properties"

Set the shortcut properties to:

```
Target:
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "cd C:\fake\example\directory & C: & ipython notebook --pylab inline"

Start in:
C:\fake\example\directory\
```

(Note the added slash at the end of "start in")

This runs windows command line, changes to your working directory, and runs the ipython notebook pointed at that directory.

Drop one of these in each project folder and you'll have ipython notebook groups kept nice and separate while still just a doubleclick away.

UPDATE: IPython has removed support for the command line inlining of pylab so the fix for that with this trick is to just eliminate "--pylab inline" if you have a newer IPython version (or just don't want pylab obviously).

UPDATE FOR JUPYTER NOTEBOOK ~ version 4.1.1

On my test machines and as reported in comments below, the newest jupyter build appears to check the start directory and launch with that as the working directory. This means that the working directory override is not needed.

Thus your shortcut can be as simple as:

```
Target (if jupyter notebook in path):
    jupyter notebook

Target (if jupyter notebook NOT in path):
    C:\Users\<Your Username Here>\Anaconda\Scripts\jupyter.exe notebook
```

If jupyter notebook is not in your PATH you just need to add the full directory reference in front of the command. If that doesn't work please try working from the earlier version. Very conveniently, now "Start in:" can be empty in my tests with 4.1.1 and later. Perhaps they read this entry on SO and liked it, so long upvotes, nobody needs this anymore :)

Comment: I've found that you can just copy the shortcut that's used in the Start Menu, and make "Start In" empty, then IPython will start with the working directory as the directory the shortcut resides in.

Comment: Christoph, can you share what "Target" your icon has? I was unable to replicate the method you describe. When I leave the "Start In" empty it opens in the install directory. Can you run with "-pylab inline"? I wonder if it's my command line usage that limits my use of your shortcut.

Comment: Notice that this solution must be slightly changed with Ipython 3.1 as --pylab is not supported any longer. instead of ipython notebook "--pylab inline" write "ipython notebook"

Comment: I find this is not working for the newest version of Jupyter Notebook, is this true? Then how can I change it?

Comment: @cqcn1991 - I know they were getting reading to deprecate to a different command and was going to update this answer, maybe the time is now. Can you run the notebook normally and if so what command are you using. If not, then the problem is elsewhere. I will update for new version if command needs it.

Comment: I can run `jupyter notebook` in cmd, in the working directory. I just can't set the `start in` to make notebook start in the desired dir.

Comment: @cqcn1991 - please see my update. In my test with 4.1.1 you can just put in "jupyter notebook" (no quotes) in the Target: field and leave Start in: field empty and it runs where the shortcut is.

Comment: This would be removed in fututre versions and is no longer supported.

Comment: @shahar_m Can be tell us what you mean by "This" for what will not be supported? Did you see the updates for 4.11 at the bottom?

Comment: @EzekielKruglick I get the following text after running the suggested: [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
[E 17:13:51.973 NotebookApp] Support for specifying --pylab on the command line has been removed.
[E 17:13:51.973 NotebookApp] Please use `%pylab inline` or `%matplotlib inline` in the notebook itself.

Comment: @shahar_m - Yes, this is documented in my response at the update for 4.1.1    They changed the name to jupyter and the command line, see the second code block in the answer, that is exactly your scenario.

Answer (score 37):

In iPython Notebook on Windows, this worked for me:

```
cd d:\folder\
```

Comment: Works in Linux as well, for example, `cd ~/whatever`

Answer (score 36):

Besides @Matt's approach, one way to change the default directory to use for notebooks **permanently** is to change the config files. Firstly in the cmdline, type:

```
$> ipython profile create
```

to initialize a profile with the default configuration file. Secondly, in file `ipython_notebook_config.py`, uncomment and edit this line:

```
# c.NotebookManager.notebook_dir = 'D:\\Documents\\Desktop'
```

changing `D:\\Documents\\Desktop` to whatever path you like.

This works for me ;)

UPDATE: There is no `c.NotebookManager.notebook_dir` anymore.
Now, the line to uncomment and config is this one:
`c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'Z:\\username_example\folder_that_you_whant'`

Comment: In case you are using Jupyter the command changes to "jupyter notebook --generate-config" and the line to modify in "jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py" is "c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir ="

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me.

Answer (score 22):

Usually `$ ipython notebook` will launch the notebooks and kernels at he current working directory of the terminal.

But if you want to specify the launch directory, you can use `--notebook-dir` option as follows:

`$ ipython notebook --notebook-dir=/path/to/specific/directory`

Answer (score 18):

## Before runing ipython:

1. Change directory to your preferred directory
2. Run ipython

## After runing ipython:

1. Use  `%cd /Enter/your/prefered/path/here/`
2. Use `%pwd` to check your current directory

Comment: As a decent solution, I suggest using virtualenvwrapper to assign a directory to each environment. In addition to all perks of virtual environments, by activating each environment you can be directed to a specific directory. Please take a look at the documentation from the following link:
https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#project-directory-management
In case you use anaconda distribution of python, you can use the

Answer (score 13):

A simpler modification to the Windows Trick above -  without the need to hard-code the directory.

A) Create a batch file with the following contents:
  (Note: A batch file is a simple text file containing commands that can
    be run in the cmd window.  It must have a '.bat' extension, therefore ...
    you'll need to disable the folder setting which hides extensions of known types)

```
rem -- start_ipython_notebook_here.bat ---
dir
ipython notebook 
pause
```

B) Copy and paste the batch file to any folder you want to start a notebook server in.

(Make sure it's a folder that you have permission to edit. "C:\" is not a good choice.)

C) Double-click on the batch file in Windows Explorer.

The notebook server should start as it normally does.

Comment: This is the best. It is convenient to switch the directory.

Comment: I find this as best solution. Replace `ipython notebook` with `jupyter notebook` as the former is deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

For linux and Windows:
Just modify 1 line, and you can change it.

```
1. Open file
```

> cwp.py

in

> C:\Users\ [your computer name]\Anaconda2

.

```
2. find the line
```

> os.chdir(documents_folder)

at the end of the file.

Change it to

> os.chdir("your expected working folder")

for example: os.chdir("D:/Jupyter_folder")

```
3. save and close.
```

It worked.

---

**Update**:

When it comes to MacOS, I couldn't find the cwp.py.
Here is what I found:

Open terminal on your Macbook, run '**jupyter notebook --generate-config**'.

It will create a config file at */Users/[your_username]/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py*

Open the config file, then change this line **#c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''**
to 
**c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '*your path*'** 
and remember un-comment this line too.

For example, I change my path to '/Users/catbuilts/JupyterProjects/'

Comment: Works for me, on MacOS Ventura 13.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

According to official Jupyter Notebook Documentation Change

> %USERPROFILE%

to your folder path

[Documentation Link](http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html)

3.1.1. Change Jupyter Notebook startup folder (Windows)

- Copy the Jupyter Notebook launcher from the menu to the desktop.
- Right click on the new launcher and change the Target field, change %USERPROFILE% to the full path of the folder which will contain all the notebooks.
- Double-click on the Jupyter Notebook desktop launcher (icon shows [IPy]) to start the Jupyter Notebook App. The notebook interface will appear in a new browser window or tab. A secondary terminal window (used only for error logging and for shut down) will be also opened.

[image]

Comment: make sure to enclose your path with in double quotes EG: `"F:/YourPath"`

Comment: As per SO guidelines, answers must be given in actual text, not images of text. Text in images can be difficult to read on mobile devices, is not accessibility friendly, takes too much bandwidth for some users, and cannot be copy-pasted. Images are to be reserved for things that only a picture can show, when a picture is relevant and necessary. In some cases, an image can also be included as supplementary material to complement an answer. But text as an image cannot BE the answer. Please edit by typing in the directions above the dialog box image, and delete the website screenshot of text.

Answer (score 9):

OS Windows 10
Python Anaconda 2018 ver

CHANGE WORKING DIRECTORY OF JUPYTER NOTEBOOK BY CONFIGURATION FILE:

1. Open cmd prompt (or Anaconda Prompt), then type 'jupyter notebook --generate-config' and press enter
2. This auto create a file 'jupyter_notebook_config' in the 'C:\Users\username.jupyter\' folder
3. Look for the created file 'jupyter_notebook_config'and edit it.
4. Find for  #c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''
5. Put you're desired path inside double quote, it becomes --->  c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:/my_folder/jupiter'

   - Note the forward slash (/) is used, and the comment (#) was remove.

Hence,

```
#c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''
```

Edit to becomes

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:/your/desired/path'
```

6. Let's modify the path of the Jupyter Notebook shortcut icon
   6.0 On start menu, right-click on the shortcut, open folder location.
   6.1 Once inside the folder, recommended to create a copy of Jupyter shortcut, 
   6.2 right click on the new shortcut icon  to open properties,

Finally,

6.3 on Target text box, remove **%USERPROFILE%** at the end of path, The very long path should end with *jupyter-notebook-script.py*

searcch my vid
Jupyter Notebook - Change working folder path from default to desired path

Answer (score 8):

just change to the preferred directory in CMD, so if you are in

```
C:\Users\USERNAME>
```

just change the path like this

```
C:\Users\USERNAME>cd D:\MyProjectFolder
```

the CMD cursor then will move to this folder

```
D:\MyProjectFolder>
```

next you can call jupyter

```
D:\MyProjectFolder>jupyter notebook
```

Comment: This is the simplest method for me.

Comment: Frankly this should be the upvoted accepted answer the others are way too complicated.

Answer (score 5):

To do the same trick described below for Windows in OS X, create this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname "$0") && pwd
ipython notebook
```

Call it ipython-notebook.command and make it executable.

Put it in the directory you want to work in, then double-click it.

Answer (score 5):

When launched from the command line, the IPython Notebook will use your current working directory. I took advantage of this and created context menu entries to open it directly from Windows Explorer. No need for shortcuts or batch scripts!

I was inspired by the registry-based 'Git GUI Here/Git Bash Here' entries created by Git for Windows. [This page](http://web.archive.org/web/20131110010314/http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm) (archived version linked) was helpful in locating the correct keys.

This first pair is for the context menu presented with nothing selected (e.g. the directory background). The notebook will open with the current directory as it's working directory.

```
Key: HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\ipythonnb
Value: &IPython Notebook Here

Key: HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\ipythonnb\command
Value: "<full path to IPython notebook>" "%v"
```

This pair is for the context menu presented when clicking on a folder. The notebook will open with the selected folder as it's working directory.

```
Key: HKCR\Directory\shell\ipythonnb
Value: &IPython Notebook Here

Key: HKCR\Directory\shell\ipythonnb\command
Value: "<full path to IPython notebook>" "%1"
```

Pay attention to `%v` vs `%1` arguments or it won't work. Don't forget the quotes either. On my platform the full path to IPython Notebook is `C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\IPython Notebook.exe` but this value will obviously dependent on your installation.

**Edit:** AFAICT  the full path is required even if the executable is on the system path.

Comment: This should be the best answer IMO

Answer (score 3):

Locate your ipython binary. If you have used anaconda to install ipython-notebook on a mac, chances are it will be in the `/Users/[name]/anaconda/bin/` directory

in that directory, instead of launching your notebook as

```
./ipython notebook
```

add a `--notebook-dir=<unicode>` option.

```
./ipython notebook --notebook-dir=u'../rel/path/to/your/python-notebooks'
```

I use a bashscript in my ipython bin directory to launch my notebooks:

```
DIR=$(dirname $0)
$DIR/ipython notebook --notebook-dir=u'../rel/path/to/your/python-notebooks'
```

Note - the path to the notebook dir is relative to the ipython bin directory.

Answer (score 3):

Simply follow [the guide on the official site](http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html#change-jupyter-notebook-startup-folder-windows), also copied below. For the first step, instead of copying the launcher, you can just go to start menu and right click to open the location.

> 1. Copy the Jupyter Notebook launcher from the menu to the desktop.
> 2. Right click on the new launcher and change the “Start in” field by pasting the full path of the folder which will contain all the notebooks.
> 3. Double-click on the Jupyter Notebook desktop launcher (icon shows [IPy]) to start the Jupyter Notebook App, which will open in a new browser window (or tab). Note also that a secondary terminal window (used only for error logging and for shut down) will be also opened. If only the terminal starts, try opening this address with your browser: http://localhost:8888/.

Answer (score 2):

On MiniConda2/Anaconda2 under Windows to change Jupyter or iPython working directory, you can modify this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Miniconda2\cwp.py
```

and add your project folder location: *development_folder= 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Development'*
Which is My Username \ Development in my case.

also change: *os.chdir(documents_folder)* to *os.chdir(development_folder)*

```
try:
    documents_folder = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.Documents)
    development_folder= 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Development'
except PathNotFoundException:
    documents_folder = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.PublicDocuments)
os.chdir(development_folder)
subprocess.call(args, env=env)
```

Execute by using your regular Jupiter Notebook shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone who doesn't want to change config file. If you are on Windows/ using Anaconda3, go to Win `Start ->Search for  Jupyter Notebook(env).`
Click on it and the Jupyter opens up. On Jupyter webpage, on right hand side go to `New -> Terminal` and the terminal window opens up. In this terminal windows change the directory to the working directory, using cd command. Example: `cd "c:\User\<user-name>\workingdir".`  Now in the same terminal window type `Jupyter-notebook`, this will open Jupyter with the working directory we used in `cd command` above.

Answer (score 1):

I have both 32 and 64 bit python and ipython using WinPython, I wanted both 32 and 64 bit versions to point to the same working directory for ipython notebook.

I followed the above suggestions here I was still unable to get my setup working.

Here's what I did - in case anyone needs it:

---

It looks like Ipython notebook was using the configuration from `C:\pythonPath\winpythonPath\settings\.ipython\profile_default`

**Even though** `ipython locate` returns `C:\users\Username\.ipython`

As a result, modifying the ipython_notebook_config.py file did nothing to change my working directory.

Additionally `ipython profile_create` was not creating the needed python files in `C:\pythonPath\winpythonPath\settings\.ipython\profile_default`

**I'm sure there's a better way**, but to resolve this quickly, I **copied** the edited python files from `C:\users\Username\.ipython\profile_default` to `C:\pythonPath\winpythonPath\settings\.ipython\profile_default`

Now (finally) ipython notebook 64 bit runs and provides me the correct working directory

Note on Windows I'm having no issue with the following syntax:

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'C:/Users/Path_to_working_directory'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ipython in linux, then follow the steps:

`!cd /directory_name/`

You can try all the commands which work in you linux terminal.

`!vi file_name.py`

Just specify the exclamation(!) symbol before your linux commands.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to the long list of answers here. If you are on Windows/ using Anaconda3, I accomplished this by going to the file /Scripts/ipython-script.py, and just added the lines

```
import os
os.chdir(<path to desired dir>)
```

before the line

```
sys.exit(IPython.start_ipython())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/')
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X with blanks in target directory (follow up to @pheon). Add extra pair of double quotes around $(...) in line 2 thus. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308838 (Sean Bright)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd
ipython notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very effective method to save the notebooks in a desired location in windows.

1. One-off activity: Make sure the path of `jupyter-notebook.exe` is
   saved under environment variable.
2. Open your desired directory either from windows explorer or by cd
   from command prompt
3. From the windows explorer on your desired folder, select the address
   bar(in a way that the path label is fully selected) and type `jupyter-notebook.exe`
4. voila!! the notebook opens from the
   desired folder and any new notebook will be saved in this location.

Answer (score 0):

In command line before typing "`jupyter notebook`" navigate to the desired folder.

In my case my all python files are in "D:\Python".

Then type the command "jupyter notebook" and there you have it. You have changed your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

This question keeps coming up when I search for `ipython change pwd` even though I am not interested in a `notebook`, but a terminal or qtconsole.  Not finding a relevant config entry I tried:

```
# lines of code to run at IPython startup.
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%cd /home/paul/mypy']
```

This is the base level `shell` class; there are Terminal and Console (and probably notebook) entries that could further customize the action.

From the docs it looks like `import` statements are most common in the entry, but it appears that many magic commands work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ipython in windows, then follow the steps:

1. navigate to ipython notebook in programs and right click on it and
   go to properties.
2. In shortcut Tab , change the 'Start in' directory to your desired
   directory.
3. Restart the kernal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) with a simple script to open a Jupyter Notebook server in a default directory (CTRL+I) or a path highlighted in explorer (or elsewhere with CTRL+SHIFT+I).

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoTrayIcon

SetTitleMatchMode RegEx

; Press CTRL+ALT+I in a Windows Explorer window to launch a IPython notebook server in the current folder.
^+!i::
; Get the current path.
Send ^l
; Backup the current clipboard.
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
; Copy and save the current path.
Send ^c
ClipWait
x = %Clipboard%
; Restore the clipboard.
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved = ; Free the memory in case the clipboard was very large.
; Now, run the IPython notebook server.
RunWait, ipython notebook --notebook-dir "%x%", , min
return

^i::
; Now, run the IPython notebook server.
RunWait, jupyter notebook --notebook-dir "C:\Path\To\Workspace", , min
return

; Press CTRL+ALT+P to kill all Python processes.
^!p::
Run, taskkill /f /im python.exe, , min
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Upper Solution may not work for you if you have installed latest version of Python in Windows. I have installed Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit) and I wanted to change the working directory of iPython Notebook called Jupyter and this is how it worked for me.

**Step-1 :**  Open your CMD and type following command.

[Step1 : CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlWiI.png)

**Step-2 :** It has now generated a file in your .jupyter folder. For me, it's C:\Users\Admin.jupyter . There you will find a file called jupyter_notebook_config.py .Right click and edit it. Add the following line and set path of your working directory.
[Set your own working directory in place of "I:\STUDY\Y2-Trimester-1\Modern Data Science"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZPTE.png)

We are done. Now you can try restarting your Jupyter Notebook. Hope this is useful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the [nbopen](https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen) module. When you install and integrate it with the windows explorer, you will be able to open any notebook by double clicking on it.