# IPython Notebook save location

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I just started IPython Notebook, and I tried to use "Save" to save my progress. However, instead of saving the *.ipynb in my current working directory, it is saved in my python/Scripts folder. Would there be a way to set this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the notebooks location in your profile configuration. Since it's not saving them to the directory where you started the notebook, I assume that you have this option set in your profile. You can find out the the path to the profiles directory by using:

```
$ ipython locate
```

Either in your default profile or in the profile you use, edit the `ipython_notebook_config.py` file and change the lines:

*Note: In case you don't have a profile, or the profile folder does not contain the `ipython_notebook_config.py` file, use `ipython profile create`.*

```
# The directory to use for notebooks.
c.NotebookManager.notebook_dir = u'/path/to/your/notebooks'
```

and

```
# The directory to use for notebooks.
c.FileNotebookManager.notebook_dir = u'/path/to/your/notebooks'
```

Or just comment them out if you want the notebooks saved in the current directory.

**Update (April 11th 2014):** in IPython 2.0 the property name in the config file changed, so it's now:

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'/path/to/your/notebooks'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Viktor! One other (greedy) question - do you know if it's possible for me to change this folder dynamically in the notebook itself? Thanks!

Comment: @ShawnWang Not that I know. :-/

Comment: Sorry for keep bothering... Any idea if I cannot find ipython_notebook_config.py? I am using WinPython 2.7 64 bit in windows :)

Comment: @ShawnWang If it's not in one of the directories under the path that `ipython locate` printed out, then I don't know. Maybe WinPython set something for you. You can always create a new profile and use it: [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html#configuration-file-location)

Comment: With ipython 1.1.0 it seems ipython_notebook_config.py is **not** created by default. https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2974#issuecomment-30431951 so just copy the ipython_config.py -> ipython_notebook_config.py and go from there.

Comment: @denfromufa You already have it in the `ipython_notebook_config.py`. At the top of the file you can find: `c = get_config()`.

Comment: Thanks for the update re IPython 2.0. I had this working but it stopped after I upgraded.

Comment: Beware, since IPython 4.0 the directory is now under ~/.jupyter see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31982416/1998288) and you should create it with `jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Answer (score 15):

If you're using IPython 4.x/Jupyter, run

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

This will create a file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in `~/.jupyter`. This file already has a line starting with `# c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir=u''`.

All you need to do is to uncomment this line and change the value to your desired location, e.g., `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir=u'/home/alice/my_ipython_notebooks'`

Answer (score 8):

Just `cd` to your working folder and then start the `IPython notebook server`. This way you can be mobile.

Comment: That's very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To add to Victor's answer, I was able to change the save directory on Windows using...

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Folder'
```

Comment: Nice pull for us windows users. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Based on my experience, if you use "ipython.exe" in python-2.7.5/Scripts from other directory, as typing at the comamnd prompt as *ipython notebook*, *.ipynb files will be loaded and saved in the current directory. ("notebook" is just a comamnd line parameter) I think the "ipython notebook.exe" in Winpython top directory is not relevant for your request. As for me, I added the ipython.exe directory to the Path only.
2. If you want to make your profile in user directory, see below:
   https://code.google.com/p/winpython/wiki/Installation#Settings

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter under the [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) environment has a batch file in the `scripts` folder called:

```
make_working_directory_be_not_winpython.bat
```

You need to edit the following line in it:

```
echo WINPYWORKDIR = %%HOMEDRIVE%%%%HOMEPATH%%\Documents\WinPython%%WINPYVER%%\Notebooks>>"%winpython_ini%"
```

replacing the `Documents\WinPython%%WINPYVER%%\Notebooks` part with your folder address.

Notice that the `%%HOMEDRIVE%%%%HOMEPATH%%\` part will identify the root and user folders (i.e. `C:\Users\your_name\`) which will allow you to point different WinPython installations on separate computers to the same cloud storage folder (e.g. OneDrive) where you could store, access, and work with the same files from different machines. I find that very useful.

Answer (score 1):

To run in Windows, copy this *.bat file to each directory you wish to use and run the ipython notebook by executing the batch file. This assumes you have ipython installed in windows.

```
set "var=%cd%"
cd var
ipython notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other solutions, but I didn't find that `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` setting in the config...

```
#jupyter_notebook_config.json

{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "nbserver_extensions": {
      "jupyter_nbextensions_configurator": true
    }
  }
}
```

So, what I do is:

- `cd` into the directory where I want the notebooks and checkpoints
  saved
- start the notebook server `jupyter-lab`
- then, in an active notebook cell, I change my working directory so that the code in my python cells can access my other modules =)

```
# ipython cell
import os

# change where notebooks are stored
os.chdir('/Users/me/Project')
os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with writing a set of codes on a jupiter notebook file and wish to upload your file to your github account, use this format to download the file directly to the computer local disk first

```
%notebook "directory/to/file/filename.ipynb"
```

Example:

```
%notebook "C:\Users\john\Documents\Python Projects/filename.ipynb"
```

The files are saved automatically to your folder, then you can upload them to the git account.