# IPython notebook won't read the configuration file

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I used the following command to initialize a profile:

```
ipython profile create myserver
```

Added thses lines to `~/.ipython/profile_myserver/ipython_notebook_config.py`:

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8889
```

Tried starting the notebook with:

```
ipython notebook --profile=myserver --debug
```

It does not read the config file at all.
This is the log output:

```
[W 16:26:56.607 NotebookApp] Unrecognized alias: '--profile=myserver', it will probably have no effect.
[D 16:26:56.609 NotebookApp] Config changed:
[D 16:26:56.609 NotebookApp] {'profile': u'myserver', 'NotebookApp': {'log_level': 10}}
...
[I 16:26:56.665 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:26:56.665 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
```

Since I've explicitly specified port 8889 and it still runs on 8888, it clearly ignores the config file. What am I missing?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: IPython 4.0.0.
python 2.7.9.
@Cyphase

Comment: Try `ipython --profile=myserver notebook --debug`. If it works, I'll post an answer.

Comment: It terminates with following messages.
``[TerminalIPythonApp] Loading IPython extension: storemagic
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'notebook'
[TerminalIPythonApp] IPython not interactive...``

Comment: Using your original command line, try putting the configuration in `~/.ipython/profile_myserver/ipython_config.py` instead of `~/.ipython/profile_myserver/ipython_notebook_config.py`.

Comment: Already put the config in both those files. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try setting the IP to `'localhost'` instead of `'*'`. Just in case. Make sure one file isn't messing with the other.

Comment: It still doesn't work.
From log I can see that it reads the config. 
But it complains about this:
``[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'notebook'
[TerminalIPythonApp] IPython not interactive...``

Comment: Wait, isn't that the error you got from trying the command I gave? I meant for you to go back to using the one in your question :).

Comment: I see! I'm using this: ``ipython notebook --profile=myserver --debug`` Still the same problem. Runs on 8888. Doesn't read the config. And both config files are the same

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is actually running on port 8888 and not 8889? It's highly unlikely that it would be inconsistent in that way, but I would check to get that out of the way :P.

Comment: Just checked. It is not running on 8889.
I also tried it on IPython 3.1.0 and everything worked fine. What's wrong with 4.0.0?

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with the Jupyter re-org. Try using `jupyter` instead of `ipython` to start the notebook.

Comment: That was the problem! Configuring the jupyter instead of ipython and starting it with ``jupyther notebook --profile=myserver`` solved the problem.
Thanks! Please feel free to add the answer :)

Comment: Done. Also, I added the 'jupyter' tag to your post, but you could just do it yourself, as my edit needs to be approved. That'll make it easier for people to find. I expect others will be running into this over the next few days and beyond, as the new versions were just released.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

IPython has now moved to **[version 4.0](http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/08/12/first-release-of-jupyter/)**, which means that if you are using it, it will be reading its configuration from `~/.jupyter`, not `~/.ipython`. You have to create a new configuration file with

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and then edit the resulting `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file according to your needs.

More installation instructions [here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html).

Comment: What happens to all the profile folders that are in `~/.ipython`? Are they ignored? Do I need to copy them over to `~/.jupyter`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, I wouldn't just copy them across, as the API changed a little. The best thing is to edit the new config manually, copying accross whatever settings you had in the old one and reading the comments in the new one to understand the API changes. Yes, they are ignored (AFAIK).

Comment: That makes sense. Not everything needs to be moved/recreated though, right? It seems like the some things (e.g.`ipython_config.py`) are still used (at least outside of notebooks). It's not clear to me where `ipython` gets reads its configuration vs. where `ipython notebook` does (or for that matter, what happens with other kernels).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, you really have to read the [installation instructions for Jupyter](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html). I didn't try it, but it seems to me that for the console application you should run `jupyter console --generate config`. For kernels I believe the process hasn't changed. I didn't do anything to them, but they work for me, so maybe it is still reading from `~/.ipython` after all.

Comment: This section in the docs was helpful: [Migrating from IPython](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html#migrating) The IPython configuration I was using for a notebook server needed no changes. After `jupyter notebook`: `The IPython Notebook is running at: https://10.0.1.207:10000/`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `ipython` command, use `jupyter`:

```
jupyter notebook --profile=myserver
```

With [the release of IPython 4.0](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2015-August/016805.html), the language-agnostic pieces of IPython, such as the notebook server, were moved to [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/). You can read more about [The Big Split](https://blog.jupyter.org/2015/04/15/the-big-split/) and [the new release of Jupyter](http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/08/12/first-release-of-jupyter/) at those links.

Comment: jupyter actually no longer has profiles either, see here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/310

Comment: @KevinDahl, hmm, then I wonder what OP meant that it solved the problem.. I'm not familiar enough with it to know.