# changing default location of anaconda

Tags: python, conda

I have installed anaconda in my pc recently(linux). The problem is, it is saving all new files in the default location which is the drive where linux os is installed(be it jupyter notebook or spyder ). Is there a way I can change the default location of opening files in anaconda to some other drive(where I wont have to change it again and again whenever opening)? A very small space is left in the default drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to move the anaconda install location you can follow the guide from the [anaconda docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory/) but it requires you to reinstall anaconda(though you can backup and restore your environments).
but if what you want is to move the location of default save location for notebooks you can do it by changing the location in the settings such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901898/13329248)