# .ipynb files visible in Jupyter but not from Windows File Explorer

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm able to see my .ipynb files when using Jupyter (installed through Anaconda), but I just can't see them in my Desktop or wherever they're saved when using Windows File Explorer. What could cause this and how can I locate the files?
Here is what I mean:

**Windows File Explorer**

[image: My desktop view]

**Jupyter**

[image: My Jupyter view]

Comment: ensure you are in the right folder try to verify with: os. getcwd()

Comment: @Glauco I'm in the right folder when I execute the os.getcwd() in the notebook.

'C:\\Users\\my_user\\Desktop'

Comment: can this be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901185/ipython-notebook-save-location

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem has you, my solution download the file through jupyter.

File -> Download.

I still can't understand the reason why but after I downloaded the file from the same folder into the same folder it start appearing in my windows explorer folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you but realized that it was just a minor thing.
For me, I had installed Anaconda only for the current user. So it was using "C:\Users\username\Desktop" and not "C:\Users\Public\Desktop". The latter is the usual Desktop that is referred to as "This PC\Desktop".

Try looking into "C:\Users\username\Desktop".