# How to start jupyter in an environment created by conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I use `conda` created an environment called `testEnv` and activated it, after that I use the command `jupyter notebook` to call the jupyter editor. It works, but the problem is that, I can only create file in the root environment. How can I create file in `testEnv` environment?

Here are the steps what I have done:

```
$ conda create -n testEnv python=3.5 # create environmet
$ source activate testEnv # activate the environmet

(testEnv)$ jupyter notebook # start the jupyter notebook
```

Here are the result, which shows I can only create file with in "root" but not in "testEnv" (There is only `Root`, but no `testEnv`):

[image]

In the Tab `Conda`, I can see the `testEnv`, but how can I switch to it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117132/change-anaconda-ipython-main-directory)?

Comment: Hi @ragesz , this answer is change the ipython main directory, but I want just use jupyter as editor for the Environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options. You can install the Jupyter Notebook into each environment, and run the Notebook from that environment:

```
conda create -n testEnv python=3.5 notebook
source activate testEnv
jupyter notebook
```

or you need to install the IPython kernel from `testEnv` into the environment from which you want to run Jupyter Notebook. Instructions are here: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments To summarize:

```
conda create -n testEnv python=3.5
source activate testEnv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name testEnv --display-name "Python (testEnv)"
source deactivate
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: just conda activated and worked fine, instead of source. (Windows 10, 64 bit, Anaconda 2021-05, Python 3.8, the test environment had python 3.9, which was also printed from Jupyter notebook cell.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you probably shouldn't do this. Python virtualenvs and Conda environments are intended to determine the resources available to the Python system, which are completely independent of your working directory.

You can use the same environment to work on multiple projects, as long as they have the same dependencies. The minute you start tweaking the environment you begin messing with something that is normally automatically maintained.

So perhaps the real question you should ask yourself is "why do I think it's a good idea to store my notebooks inside the environment used to execute them."

Comment: I downloaded the anaconda but didn't installed the jupyter, it is already there...

Comment: I'm simply saying that you should maintain your application code in an entirely separate area from the environment you use to process it.

Comment: yes, I  saved my application code in a separate folder, not in the the environment. I already jumped into a separate folder before I type `jupyter notebook`

Comment: actually, I did the same thing like this post: http://stuartmumford.uk/blog/jupyter-notebook-and-conda.html