# Autohotkey run program as admin not working

Tags: anaconda, autohotkey

I created an Autohotkey script to open the Anaconda Command Prompt. Such that when I press `Ctrl+Numpad4` I will get an anaconda prompt opened up. If I press `Ctrl+Shift+Numpad4` The anaconda prompt opens up as an admin. I followed the code instructions found in autohotkey forums; but this does not seem to work. Here's my code:

```
^Numpad4:: Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"
^NumpadLeft:: Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"

^+NumpadLeft::
RunAs, Administrator, #Mypassword
Run, "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"
RunAs

^+Numpad4::
RunAs, Administrator, #MyPassword
Run, "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"
RunAs
```

The numpad left and 4 are only to cover both possible cases with number lock on or off.

What should I do?

Also, there's another minor concern which is that anaconda opens up in the same directory as my autohotkey script. I would like it to open up at a prespecified directory. Can I do this from the autohotkey script itself. By creating a batch file or adding any additional snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

1. If you want ahk to run something for you as an admin, you need to make sure that you have AHK ask for elevation perms when running it. This can be achieved by replacing your "runas" sections with "Run *runas" For example if I was trying to elevate a cmd that I would normally call with

```
run cmd
```

I could run it elevated by calling

```
Run *runas cmd
```

So the script at this point would look smthng like

```
^Numpad4:: Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"
^NumpadLeft:: Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"

^+NumpadLeft::Run *runas "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"

^+Numpad4::Run *runas "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"
```

To address your second question, you can change what directory the script runs in by [changing your working directory](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetWorkingDir.htm).
For example, if you wanted to change your working directory to C:\Users, you would use

```
SetWorkingDir, C:\Users
```

Note: when using elevation, the working dir may change back to the User's default (for administrator: C:\WINDOWS\system32). To resolve this, you will likely need to pass additional parameters into your run command itself that will be specific to the program you are trying to run (in this case, Anaconda). I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117132/change-anaconda-ipython-main-directory) that may resolve your Anaconda issue with a different method.

So, in summary, your script would look something like this:

```
SetWorkingDir, C:\Users ;replace this directory with the one that you actually want to use

^Numpad4:: Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"

^NumpadLeft:: Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"

^+NumpadLeft::Run *runas "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"

^+Numpad4::Run *runas "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk"
```

Comment: The admin method works. However, even with setting current dir to a specific folder, the normal(not elevated) prompt opens up in the C:\Users\{My name} folder only regardless of the directory set.

Comment: But I created a temporary solution by making a copy of the shortcut in my directory with the scripts and set the default path of the shortcut to the directory I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the temporary solution:

That is because the shortcuts Anaconda.lnk **Start In:** argument is `%HOMEPATH%`, which is your user profile directory.
You can change the shortcut **Start In:** argument `%HOMEPATH%` to whatever path you need.

Or you can copy the Target of shortcut from properties which is something like:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\tools\Anaconda3
```

Then replace %windir%\System32\cmd.exe with just cmd and remove quotes:

```
cmd /K C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\tools\Anaconda3
```

And put it in the AutoHotkey script in the Run commands.

Then you can set the `SetWorkingDir C:\Program Files` or whatever you need and it should start the Anaconda from that directory.

So the script should look something like this:

```
SetWorkingDir, C:\Program Files
^Numpad4:: Run cmd /K C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\tools\Anaconda3
^NumpadLeft:: Run cmd /K C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\tools\Anaconda3
^+NumpadLeft::Run *RunAs cmd /K C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\tools\Anaconda3
^+Numpad4::Run *RunAs cmd /K C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\tools\Anaconda3
```