# Change path in every IPython notebook

Tags: python, path, ipython

I would like to change the path for every notebook that is loaded for an IPython profile. I have the following directory structure on Mac OS X:

```
/Users/user/project
├── main.py
├── reqs
├── notebooks
├── profile
└── ve, requirements.txt...
```

On this profile, I want to show the user the notebooks that are in the `notebook` folder, add this root folder to the path, and preload the `main` and `reqs` modules there.

I created a `profile` folder, and I run IPython like so:

```
$ ./ve/bin/ipython notebook --profile-dir=`pwd`/profile
```

I added the following to the file `profile/startup/00-setup.py`

```
c = get_config()

import os, sys

# Modify the path to include the core files
cur_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append('{}/../..'.format(cur_folder))

# Preload some modules
from main import *
from reqs import *
```

But somehow this doesn't have any effects, and I don't see any errors when it launches.

I found the question [Change IPython working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-working-directory) to be relevant, but in my case the path I want to add is different than the notebooks folder.

Thanks

Comment: are you using some custom shell like zsh ?

Comment: @igaurav No, I use bash. I used '$' as the prompt in the first snippet, and the second block is Python. Why ?

Comment: i thought if you messed up with $pythonpath in bashrc ? or require to ..