# anaconda iPython notebook default notebook directory - Mac OSX

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Running Conda Version: 3.7.3 on osx64

i'm trying to change the default directory that iPythonNotebook opens in from /users/me to /some/other/directory. I have tried editing  c.FileNotebookManager.notebook_dir = u'/some/other/directory' in ipython_notebook_config.py but this hasn't made a difference

The ipython_notebook_config.py is located in /Users/me/.ipython/profile_default/ . Can anaconda iPython see this config file?

Anyway some help would be much appreciated

thanks

Mark

Comment: Try setting `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir`

Comment: Attempted setting c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir. Shutdown kernel then restarted iPython notebook from Anaconda. No difference in directory Notebook opens to. I'm wondering whether i'm setting the correct config file?

Comment: `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py` should be correct. It's possible that the Anaconda launcher overrides the notebook directory with a command line argument, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22824886

If your directory name has spaces, then modify as per here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130633/1795127

Comment: thanks for looking over this after so long. I'll give it a go