# Changing Jupyter Notebook start up folder by modifying "start in" not working any more

Tags: windows, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I used to be able to change the default start up folder for Jupyter (the folder Jupyter displays in browser when it was first started) by modifying the "start in" option of the Notebook launch icon's properties on Windows, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36433389/4896087) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-working-directory/37575373#37575373).

However, this is not working any more after I recently installed Anaconda 3. Even though I changed the "start in" folder to the folder I wish, the browser still goes to "Documents" folder by default. I tried doing this as admin, still didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although a permanent fix is still not found, I do have the following workaround that works great!

Using [the way described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37575373/4896087), change the start up dir for Anaconda prompt, then launch it and make sure the default folder is the one you want, and type "jupyter notebook". There! The notebook should launch in your desired folder.

UPDATE:
You can also directly launch Anaconda Prompt, then use `cd C:\Users\Name\Folder`  to navigate into the folder where your iPython notebook files are located, and then use `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter notebook myfile.ipynb` to start working!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me to permanently fix the default working directory is by using [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23171375/1647894) by MrFancypants.

In your default directory (documents), there is a hidden folder `/.jupyter` and within it a config python file.

you can edit it and change the line

```
## The directory to use for notebooks and kernels.
#c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''
```

to

```
## The directory to use for notebooks and kernels.
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'ENTER_PATH_HERE'
```

where you should put your favorite path instead of `'ENTER_PATH_HERE`.