# How to open Jupyter notebook files located in C./D./ Drive?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to open python files located in my C. Drive, but cannot reach there, as  I can only open files located in Desktop or other files.

Comment: Try opening the jupyter notebook in the folder you need it. You can not navigate backwards (I think it's a security issue).

Comment: Alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to launch Jupyter notebook quickly at a location navigate to that location and click on the address bar and type in cmd

Once windows cmd opens up type jupyter notebook .

But if you want to change your working directory permanently look into the following stack overflow question

> [Change IPython/Jupyter notebook working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-jupyter-notebook-working-directory)

Comment: And jupyterlab?