# How to make jupyter start in current directory by default (in cmd.exe)?

Tags: windows, cmd, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In Windows 10 `cmd.exe` I can start `jupyter` in a current directory by following command:

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="."
```

The current directory is `C:\Users\Евгений\Documents\GitHub\sandbox`

However, when I start simply `jupyter notebook` in a current directory above  my working directory for jupyter is `D:/git`:

```
λ cd
C:\Users\Евгений\Documents\GitHub\sandbox
λ jupyter notebook
[I 14:46:44.273 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 14:46:44.304 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 14:46:44.304 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is D:\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 14:46:44.571 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: D:/git
```

Note the last line `Serving notebooks from local directory: D:/git`. Where is `D:/git` may be coming from? Are there environment variables [other than these](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html) affecting working directory choice?

- My `%USERPROFILE%/.jupyter` is totally empty.
- `jupyter --config-dir` directs to `C:\Users\Евгений\.jupyter`, it is `%USERPROFILE%/.jupyter`.

I read various threads about jupyter invoke, in particular:

- [this large thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-jupyter-notebook-working-directory) suggests `jupyter notebook` will behave differently in `cmd.exe` and Anaconda prompt, without further details though
- [Problems with configuring Jupyter start directory](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1730) addresses an issue with Windows shortcut, similar to this [Windows app start steps](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html#change-jupyter-notebook-startup-folder-windows)
- [this post](http://rianadam.web.ugm.ac.id/2016/03/09/change-the-default-directory-in-jupyter-notebook/) proposes wrapping `--notebook-dir="."` key into a .bat file

My other thought is that `%USERPROFILE%` with non-Latin character is not be recongnisable by `jupyter`, but `%USERPROFILE%/.jupyter` is empty anyways.

Answer (score 1):

**You must generate the configuration of Jupyter**.

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Navigate to your folder and the folder *.jupyter* (C:\Users\%username%\.jupyter)

You will find a file called ***jupyter_notebook_config.py***

Edit it with notepad++ for exemple and locate **c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir**

Between **' '** put the path you want. For exemple :

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'C:/Users/Евгений/Documents/GitHub/sandbox'
```

Save it and start **Jupyter** without specifying a path
*Be careful, the characters in your username may be a problem.*

Keep me informed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of the `notebook --generate-config` option. My specific question is where does jupyter store `D:\git` in absence of configuration file. Another internal config file?

Comment: If we don't generate a configuration, I don't think Jupyter stores another configuration file. I just know that you can switch configuration files with `jupyter -f /path/to/configFile.py`. I advise you to use [**Jupyterlab**](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). For me, the configuration with Jupyterlab works well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jupyter notebook config file:

Open `cmd` (or Anaconda Prompt) and run `jupyter notebook --generate-config`.

This writes a file to `C:\Users\username\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

Browse to the file location and open it in an Editor

Search for the following line in the file: `#c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''`

Replace by `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:/git'`

Make sure you use forward slashes in your path

Remove the # at the beginning of the line to allow the line to execute

Answer (score 0):

Using docker and the [images](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) maintained by the Jupyter team:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/home/jovyan -p 8890:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook
```