# Jupyter Anaconda: error while loading text file into python

Tags: jupyter-notebook

as u can cleary see in this picture

[image]

i have my txt file 'sunplots' in the same ordner as my python file 'test'.

If i open the python file 'test' and enter the following code:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *

data = loadtxt("sunspots.txt")
```

i always get an error

[image]

[image]

The error states there is no sunplots.txt file but how can this be? Both files are in the same folder, therefore i dont need to write the exact path and i did not write the txt file names wrong...

Comment: did you tried, restarting your kernal and run the code again?

Comment: the working directory is not necessarily the location of the notebook - debug with eg `import os` & `print(os.getcwd())` See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-jupyter-notebook-working-directory

Comment: @ vb_rises yes but i did not work out.  @9bO3... thx for that command it worked !