# How to start Jupyter Lab in current directory without changing defaults?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a default directory for my Jupyter Notebooks, and I put it in the Jupyter settings. So by default `jupytr lab` command starts my Jupyter where I need it to start.

However, sometimes I work on separate projects, and it is convenient to start Jupyter in a current working directory from a command line.

Is there an easy command to do so?

Similar question: [**Change IPython/Jupyter notebook working directory**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15680463/3730379)

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: Win, OS X, Linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TLDR: `jupyter lab .`

---

Original Answer:
Adding on to @queezz, `jupyter lab --notebook-dir=.` works too because `.` represents current directory.
Even `jupyter lab .` works

Comment: This is so much better, thank you. It works both on my win 10 and OSX.

Comment: Note: I tried this windows 10, with jupyter lab version 0.35, but generally works everywhere

Answer (score 2):

I just summarize the answers from the cited similar question here:

`jupyter lab --notebook-dir=$pwd`

Here `$pwd` returns the current directory in both Windows and OS X.

Comment: '$pwd' wasn't passing the directory string correctly for me, just an empty string. This lead to a strange error where jupyter would launch correctly but kernels would not. Copy pasting the full directory string solved the issue.

Comment: That's new. It works for me on Win and Os X. Copy and paste is to much work. Easier to remove the default folder from the settings and just use 'jupyber lab'.