# I get error , cannot import from file helper

Tags: python

Please help, I get the error below running jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from helper import boston_dataframe

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
```

Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a6117bd64450> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 from helper import boston_dataframe
      4 
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'boston_dataframe' from 'helper' (/Users/irina/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/helper/__init__.py)
```

Comment: I suspect that you installed `helper` which is this code: https://github.com/gmr/helper available from pypi under the `helper` project. It does not contain a `boston_dataframe` variable. So the question here is which `helper` are you suppose to use for this notebook? Is there a `helper` code somewhere distributed with this notebook?

Comment: there is a helper file that came with the notebook. i have downloaded it. It works for other notebooks but not fr this one

Comment: This seems like a relative path. See the below answer. If you want to use it more generally then you will want to include it in a number of ways, such as adding the directory to PYTHONPATH. But having this specific code in the same place will be clear which `helper` library/module you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not giving the where you get the notebook, I have to guess that you get it from this course [Supervised Learning: Regression](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/supervised-learning-regression/linear-regression-demo-part1-AQt6C) provided IBM.

In the zip folder in week 1, it provides `helper.py`.

[image: labwork]

What you need to do it is to change the directory to where this file is. [Change IPython/Jupyter notebook working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-jupyter-notebook-working-directory)

Alternatively, you can load boston data from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html) then load it to [Pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Advices for you:

- [Learn how to use Jupyter notebook](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tutorial/)
- [Learn how Python import work](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)
- [Learn how to provide information in a question so that no one need to guess](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)