# How to change the working directory in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, working-directory

I'm a beginner in Python Programming and I'm currently using the Anaconda Individual Edition on my MacBook.

How to change the permanent working directory for Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Hi @Kausik Welcome to SO. Could you detail more, for example if you are using terminal and launching jupyter-notebook then the current working directory is the project/files directory.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-jupyter-notebook-working-directory) might help.

Comment: Hi @coldy I open Jupyter Notebook using the Anaconda Navigator. And my pwd is /Users/admin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change IPython/Jupyter notebook working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-jupyter-notebook-working-directory)